# multiplying data frames conditionally in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiplication

I want to multiply two data.frames that are of unequal length
If I have a data frame of observations (in reality this is around 30000 entries long)

```
Species    number
1          3
1          3
3          5
4          40
5          22
```

and another data frame with conversion ratios for each species present in the first data frame (this is only about 120 entries in length)

```
species    conversion ratio
1          3
2          5
3          4
4          2
5          2
```

and I want to multiply each number column entry by the conversion ratio entry associated with that Species, how might I go about doing this in R?

I've attempted using the match function to no avail, and my attempts at working with arrays have only resulted in errors, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `?merge`. Assuming you have `species` named consistently (capitals):

```
df3 <- merge(df1,df2)
df3$number*df3$conversion.ratio
```

Comment: The merge step does not produce the desired dataframe.  It produces a much longer dataframe

Comment: @Frank What dimensions of the data frame were you expecting?  If you just want to remove the duplicated rows, try `df4 <- subset(df3, !duplicated(df3))`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I ended up with a data frame millions of entries long, when the data frame I desired should have been ~30,000 entries for each column.  I think this was because, as @ James mentioned, the two columns did not have identical names (i.e species vs. Species).  I renamed them to be the same, in which case using the `,by="species"` addition to the `merge()` function is unnecessary and your proposed solution works perfectly once the columns are renamed. Sorry, I did not understand at first when @James said "Assuming you have `species` named consistently (capitals)."

Comment: @Frank It seems that its working now, but the other way of doing this would be to compress your large `data.frame` to the same size as the smaller one - ie one row for each species. `aggregate`, `tapply`, or `xtabs` would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You could merge the two data frames.

```
## Your example data
df.number <- matrix(c(1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 40, 22), ncol = 2)
colnames(df.number) <- c("species", "number")
df.ratio <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 2, 2), ncol = 2)
colnames(df.ratio) <- c("species", "ratio")

## Merge the two matrices
dat <- merge(df.number, df.ratio, by = "species")

## Multiply for your result
result <- with(dat, number * ratio)
```

**Edit**

@Frank: In your comment to James, you say that the resulting data frame after the merge is too long.  Do you mean that you want to remove duplicated rows?  If so:

```
dat2 <- subset(dat, subset = !duplicated(dat))
result2 <- with(dat2, number * ratio)
```